# Number of days between two epoch days in scala

Tags: java, scala, date-difference

I have two epoch timestamps, I am trying to find the number of days between the two timestamps.

This is what I have now:

```
dateFrom = inputEntry.getValue(inputFields(0).get).asInstanceOf[String].toLong
dateTo =inputEntry.getValue(inputFields(1).get).asInstanceOf[String].toLong
```

Example:

```
dateFrom    dateTo      result
1501583232  1501641000  1
1501583232  1501986600  5
```

I am starting with two epoch dates here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the number of days, weeks, and months, since Epoch in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158053/get-the-number-of-days-weeks-and-months-since-epoch-in-java)

Comment: That is not a duplicate. This Question starts with a count of seconds from epoch.

Comment: that is true, but it is easily extendable to count days between two dates by subtracting these days from epoch

Comment: "Easily extendable" does not make for an "exact duplicate" per Stack Overflow requirements. Converting a count of seconds to dates is way too big a challenge to ignore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( … , … )
```

## Details

This has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. So briefly here…

For date-time values, use date-time objects. Use java.time classes only, avoid the troublesome legacy date-time classes ( Date, Calendar, etc).

Do you mean a difference of dates or a difference of 24-hour chunks of time?

I'll go with dates here.

First, translate what appears to be number of whole seconds since an epoch reference date of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z into a point in the timeline in UTC.

Note the `L` on the end of numeric literal to indicate a long rather than int.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( 1_501_583_232L ) ;
```

Assign time zone for which you want to consider dates.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

Convert to a date-only.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

Get difference.

```
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( ld , ld2 ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the results you want, you must define how you're going to calculate the difference.

Taking your first example (difference between 1501583232 and 1501641000 should be 1 day):

The epochs 1501583232 and 1501641000 are the number of seconds since `1970-01-01T00:00Z`, so they are equivalent to the following UTC dates:

```
1501583232: 2017-08-01T10:27:12Z
1501641000: 2017-08-02T02:30:00Z
```

Note that the difference between them is 16 hours, 2 minutes and 48 seconds (so, less than a day). If you get the difference in days, technically it will be zero.

But if you consider **only** the dates (`2017-08-01` and `2017-08-02`) and **ignore** the time (hour/minute/second), then the difference can be either zero or 1, depending on the timezone you are.

If you consider only the UTC dates (`2017-08-01` and `2017-08-02`), the difference is 1 day.

But if you take the same UTC dates above in `America/Los_Angeles` timezone, you'll get:

```
1501583232: 2017-08-01T03:27:12-07:00
1501641000: 2017-08-01T19:30-07:00
```

Now the difference is zero days, no matter if you consider only the date (both are `2017-08-01`), or the date and time (the difference in hours will be 16, less than a day).

So, you must define how you're going to calculate the difference (consider only the date, or both date and time, and what timezone will be used).

---

In your case, it seems that you're considering only the date and ignoring the time, but it's not clear what timezone it's using. Anyway, you can use JDK's 8 [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) for that (for JDK <= 7 you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) - The code below works for both. The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same).

The code is basically the same of [@BasilBourque's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45437811/7605325), because it's very straighforward with the new API (I just wanted to add the insights above).

First you create the `Instant`'s from the epoch values:

```
Instant instant1 = Instant.ofEpochSecond(1501583232L);
Instant instant2 = Instant.ofEpochSecond(1501641000L);
```

If you want the difference considering the date and time, you can use:

```
ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(instant1, instant2);
```

The result will be zero.

If you want to consider only the dates in UTC (and ignore the time), just do:

```
// convert to UTC and get just the date (day/month/year)
LocalDate d1 = instant1.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate();
LocalDate d2 = instant2.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate();
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(d1, d2);
```

The result will be 1.

To convert to a different timezone (instead of UTC), use the `ZoneId` class:

```
// use a specific timezone
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
// convert the Instant to a timezone and get only the date
LocalDate d1 = instant1.atZone(zone).toLocalDate();
LocalDate d2 = instant2.atZone(zone).toLocalDate();
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(d1, d2);
```

In this case, the difference is 1, but as I said above, different timezones can produce different results (can be either zero or 1 - for example, changing the code above to `ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles")`, the result is zero).

---

Note that the API uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `Asia/Kolkata` or `Europe/Berlin`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `CST` or `IST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231).

You can get a list of available timezones (and choose the one that fits best your system) by calling `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.

You can also use the system's default timezone with `ZoneId.systemDefault()`, but this can be changed without notice, even at runtime, so it's better to explicity use a specific one.